# Best way to remove duplicates from DataTable depending on column values

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I have a `DataSet` which contains just one `Table`, so you could say I'm working with a DataTable here.

**The code you see below works, but I want to have the best and most efficient way** to perform the task because I work with some data here.

Basically, the data from the Table should later be in a Database, where the primary key - of course - must be unique.

The primary key of the data I work with is in a column called `Computer Name`. For each entry we also have a date in another column `date`.

I wrote a function which searches for duplicates in the `Computer Name` column, and then compare the dates of these duplicates to delete all but the newest.

The Function I wrote looks like this:

```
private void mergeduplicate(DataSet importedData)
{
    Dictionary<String, List<DataRow>> systems = new Dictionary<String, List<DataRow>>();
    DataSet importedDataCopy = importedData.Copy();
    importedData.Tables[0].Clear();
    foreach (DataRow dr in importedDataCopy.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        String systemName = dr["Computer Name"].ToString();
        if (!systems.ContainsKey(systemName)) 
        {
            systems.Add(systemName, new List<DataRow>());
        }
        systems[systemName].Add(dr);
    }


    foreach (KeyValuePair<String,List<DataRow>> entry in systems) {
        if (entry.Value.Count > 1) {
            int firstDataRowIndex = 0;
            int secondDataRowIndex = 1;
            while (entry.Value.Count > 1) {
                DateTime time1 = Validation.ConvertStringIntoDateTime(entry.Value[firstDataRowIndex]["date"].ToString());
                DateTime time2 = Validation.ConvertStringIntoDateTime(entry.Value[secondDataRowIndex]["date"].ToString());

                //delete older entry
                if (DateTime.Compare(time1,time2) >= 0) {
                    entry.Value.RemoveAt(firstDataRowIndex);
                } else {
                    entry.Value.RemoveAt(secondDataRowIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        importedData.Tables[0].ImportRow(entry.Value[0]);
    }
}
```

My Question is, since this code works - what is the best and fastest/most efficient way to perform the task?

I appreciate any answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done more efficiently.  You copy the DataSet once with `DataSet importedDataCopy = importedData.Copy();` and then you copy it again into a dictionary and then you delete the unnecessary data from the dictionary.  I would rather just remove the unnecessary information in one pass.  What about something like this:

```
private void mergeduplicate(DataSet importedData)
{
    Dictionary<String, DataRow> systems = new Dictionary<String, DataRow>();
    int i = 0;

    while (i < importedData.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
    {
        DataRow dr = importedData.Tables[0].Rows[i];
        String systemName = dr["Computer Name"].ToString();
        if (!systems.ContainsKey(systemName)) 
        {
            systems.Add(systemName, dr);
        }
        else
        {
            // Existing date is the date in the dictionary.
            DateTime existing = Validation.ConvertStringIntoDateTime(systems[systemName]["date"].ToString());

            // Candidate date is the date of the current DataRow.
            DateTime candidate = Validation.ConvertStringIntoDateTime(dr["date"].ToString());

            // If the candidate date is greater than the existing date then replace the existing DataRow
            // with the candidate DataRow and delete the existing DataRow from the table.
            if (DateTime.Compare(existing, candidate) < 0) 
            {
                importedData.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(systems[systemName]);
                systems[systemName] = dr;
            }
            else
            {
                importedData.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(dr);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! do you think this works? I haven't tried ist but in your last Line you set `systems[systemName]` to `dr` - but `systems[systemName]` is a `List<DataRow>`

Comment: That was a typo.  It should be `Dictionary<String, DataRow>`.  I am getting rid of the `List<DataRow>` in favor of only keeping the DataRow with the most recent date.

Comment: Yeah this works! But Since I need the data in the `importedData` variable, I need to copy it back again, or? I used `importedData.Tables.RemoveAt(0); importedData.Tables.Add(systems.Values.CopyToDataTable());`. -- Do I need this second copy or can I get rid of this too?

Comment: Ah, my impression what that you were trying to get the correct values to insert into a table.  I see now that you want to delete values from the existing `DataSet`.  I should be able to modify this with a while loop shortly.

Comment: This is an endless loop - I am not 100% sure but I think you missed an `i++` in the else part of the date comparison, because If the candidate is not newer, we don't remove an entry and would have the same datarow in the next iteration - I hope you can confirm my observation. I added it in my code and this works -- Thank you! :)

Comment: Yep, that was a mistake on my part.  I was expecting the deleted row to be removed from the `DataTable` immediately (thereby reducing the row count by 1).  Instead, `Remove` simply flags the row for removal.  It is not actually removed until `AcceptChanges` is called.  That being the case you could still use a foreach loop if you were more comfortable with that syntax.  I will edit the answer to reflect your correction.

Comment: Hey, I recognized another mistake in this code, there are still duplicates. The good news is, I have fixed it - the previous increment after the `systems.Add(systemName, dr);` was completly correct, the last you have added have to be removed - because we only need an increment if we do not remove a `DataRow`. So we need to change the `if` statement where the dates get compared. I will do this in your post. I already tested it and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the most efficient way but you said you appreciate any answers

```
List<DataRow> toDelete =  dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                                .GroupBy(s => s["Computer Name"])
                                .SelectMany(grp => grp.OrderBy(x => x["date"])
                                .Skip(1)).ToList();
toDelete.ForEach(x => dt.Rows.Remove(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `CopyToDataTable`, like this:

```
importedData.Tables[0] = importedData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
       .GroupBy(r => new {CN = r["Computer Name"], Date = r["date"]})
       .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r["Date"]).(First())
       .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Sadly, importedData.Tables[0] is read only, so this won't work, anyway, thank you!